# closed jscript for loop to switchstatement

Tags: javascript, for-loop, switch-statement

replace for loop with a switch statement somehow?

Comment: why did you delete most of your original question? It was perfectly fine, and @Felix's answer below looks weird now when seen in the context of the edited/shortened question.

Comment: In this form, the question does not make much sense anyway. `switch` and `for` loops have distinct purposes. Once normally cannot just exchange them. If my answer didn't help you than you should have pointed that out and clarified your question. But don't focus on something that *you* think is a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to loop over all radio buttons to find the clicked one. You can pass the clicked element directly to your function:

```
function planeChoice(element) {
    // element refers to the clicked radio button
    var plane = element.value;

    switch (plane) {
         //...
    }
}
```

For that to work, you have to pass `this` to your function:

```
<input type="radio"  name="planeButton"  value="152"
       onclick="planeChoice(this)" />
```

`this` refers to the HTML element you attach the event handler to, so in this case it refers to the `<input>` element.

---

To learn more about events, I suggest to read the articles on http://quirksmode.org, starting with [*Introduction to Events*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) and [*Early event handlers*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html).

---

**Two suggestions for further improvement:**

(A) You can use a **map** (which is just an plain object in JavaScript) instead of a `switch` statement to determine the corresponding message:

```
var map = {
   "152": "A small two-place-airplane for flight training",
   "172": "The smaller of two four-place airplanes"
   // ...
};
```

A map is also easier to maintain (to extend).

Once you have the value of the radio button, you can access the message with:

```
 alert(map[plane]);
```

You are not limited to store only primitive values (like strings), you can also store functions and call them if you want to do some more complex things. But to learn more about functions and how you can use them, you should read a JavaScript guide.

(B) You can  use **event delegation** instead of binding the *same* event handler to every element (this works through [*event bubbling*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)). The `click` event handler is attached to the `<form>` element:

```
<form onclick="planeChoice(event)" ...>
```

Or even better, get a reference to the form element and attach the event handler via JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onclick = planeChoice;
```

The passed event object holds information about which element was clicked:

```
function planeChoice (event) {
    event = event || window.event; // for IE
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // for IE

    if(target.type === "radio") { // if a radio button is clicked
        var plane = target.value;
        // ... further code
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the 'this' in the "planeChoice(this)" refer to?

Comment: @George: The element the event handler is bound to. So to the clicked `input` element.

Comment: @Felix Kling: sorry not following you, I'm new to programming. Can you give a specific reference? And thanks a ton for your help

Comment: @George: I added two links. But basically, what you are doing in the for loop is to get a reference to the clicked element right? You can do this shorter by passing `this` to the function because in the event handler, `this` refers to the element you attach the handler to. Maybe you should also read a JavaScript Guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: -1 for omitting the mandatory mention of jQuery in your answer! (kidding :-)

Comment: @George: What do you want to know? There is not much more to say... have a look at the two links I posted, especially *Early event handlers*. There is a whole paragraph about `this`.

Comment: +1 for giving both a newbie-friendly answer and an invitation to further study.

Comment: @George: You're welcome :) I added a bit more information, I hope it also helps a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

Can I suggest you try using jQuery? It's a useful (and popular) JavaScript library that will help reduce and simplify the code you need.

For example, the above code could be simplified to this in jQuery:

```
$('#myForm input:radio').click(function(){
    switch (this.value) {
        case "152": 
            alert("A small two-place-airplane for flight training");
            break;
        // More Options go here...
        default:
            alert("Error in JavaScript function planeChoice");
            break;
    }
});
```

It would also eliminate the need to use click handlers on each radio button.

Comment: Well, technically, a click handler is attached to each radio button. But I assume you meant that one has not attach it to each element by in the HTML.